# How many stereoisomers are present in octahedral complexes of type MA3B2C?

Tags: coordination-compounds, isomers, symmetry, cis-trans-isomerism

Does $\ce{MA3B2C}$ type have optical isomerism or just geometric isomerism? I was told that it has three isomers, two *cis* and one *trans*. Are the two *cis* isomers optically active?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! What have you attempted to do with regards to the answer to this question? We need to make sure we aren't doing your homework for you.

Comment: well i worked out that for the two cis isomers, 'b' could be trans to 'a' or 'c' , and they would be different because of the difference in arrangement, but what I cant figure out is if they're optical isomers of each other, because when I take one of the cis isomers which is 'b' being trans to 'a'  and draw its mirror image and rotate it I'm not able to bring 'b' trans to 'c' , but its mirror image does seem to be non-superimposable

Comment: Don't draw mirror images, better look for a symmetry plane in the molecule, because it is there.